# Ubuntu sudo apt-get update is failing due to connection time out

Tags: sudo

```
ratna@ip-172-31-3-169:/home/ubuntu/ACE$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease
Hit:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                    
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                               
  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (185.125.190.80), connection timed out
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                               
  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1003::111). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::1c). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1003::3c9). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (185.125.188.87), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (185.125.188.12), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is *community* support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.